# How to convert rather complex reStructuredText (rst) to markdown?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext, mkdocs

I would like to convert the [user guide of Robot Framework](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/tree/master/doc/userguide) which is written in RST (restructuredtext) to Markdown to be able to host this great peace of work as a [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) site. I have already tried to convert the html version of the guide ([see here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5614)) with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) but the result was not what I liked it to be.

Now I'd like to try to convert the original RST files which are used to generate the [html version of the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html). The source of user guide consist of several RST and other files

- roles.rst
- userguide.css
- RobotFrameworkUserGuide.rst
- bunch of .rst files inside subfolders

Is it possible to convert the whole structure at once with pandoc or other tools?

What steps would you suggest to undertake to convert the RST source to Markdown in a way that keeps the need of manual editing after conversion as low as possible (keeping in mind that updates to the source will have to be adapted to the markdown version as well)?

Comment: You need to define what you want the result to be. From the [docs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#description), "conversions from formats more expressive than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy." Also update your question to include the markdown command. For every bit that does not convert as you would like, you must write your own script to manually adjust it to what you like.

Comment: Markdown's documentation [notes](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) that "Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. ... For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself."  As RST is much more expressive than Markdown and Padoc is "lossy" (as @StevePiercy notes), Padoc is not likely to work well for anything but the simplest of RST documents.

Comment: just give it a try and report specific problems you encounter...

Comment: Also, you may want to consider alternatives to MkDocs that support ReST directly, e.g. Sphinx.